# Серия и последовательность

Tags: выбор-слов, выбор-варианта

Оба эти слова можно использовать в значении "совокупность идущих один из другим объектов". Но мне непонятны особенности выбора между ними. Например:

> В Москве проходит серия одиночных пикетов против <...>.
>
> В древней Ирландии война представляла из себя последовательность одиночных стычек.

Во втором случае вроде бы можно использовать и "последовательность" и "серию". А вот в первом — только "серию"; "последовательность" выглядит неестественной. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если требуется однозначное указание на **последовательный** характер чего-либо, то (во избежание недоразумений) выбор нужно делать в пользу слова "**последовательность**". Дело в том, что "серия" в общем случае указывает на *любую совокупность* чего-либо (это не обязательно что-то похожее на "серию выстрелов"), а "**серийный**" означает не более, чем "**принадлежность к серии**" (например, к серии или даже партии выпущенных в таком-то месяце штучных изделий). Этим русское значение заимствованного слова "серийный" отличается напр. от английского serial, что сказывается и на переводе терминов, например, в случае *serial interface* правильно "*последовательный интерфейс*" а не "серийный".